# How to find the right index for slow query (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

I have a larger table in a Azure postgresql and am currently trying to find the right query and index.

The table currently has >130.000.000 entries.

```
select COUNT(*) from foo
--19 seconds 132.158.395
```

As soon as I do a like search the query becomes very slow.

Now the question is how best to solve the problem with the like. Whether I need new indexes or need multiple queries.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo
(
    id integer primary key generated always as identity
    a text 
    b text 
    c text
    d text
)
```

Slow query:

```
select id
from foo
where 
id > 132111615
and a = 'test'
and (
    b like '123456%'
    --or 
    --c like '123456%'
)
order by id
LIMIT 1000;
```

Query Plan:

```
Limit  (cost=1000.63..321782.22 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=3841.350..6778.433 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.63..6750245.30 rows=21040 width=4) (actual time=3841.349..6778.427 rows=10 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 4
        ->  Parallel Index Scan using foo_pkey on foo  (cost=0.57..6746739.17 rows=5260 width=4) (actual time=2162.048..5820.835 rows=2 loops=5)
              Index Cond: (id > 13195851)
              Filter: ((a = 'test'::text) AND ((b ~~ '%123456%'::text) OR (c ~~ '%123456%'::text)))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 23792507
Planning Time: 0.172 ms
Execution Time: 6778.459 ms
```

In practice, the sorting could also change, other parameters could also be searched, which makes the selection so difficult.

```
select *
    from foo
    where 
    (id,d) > (132111615, 'mySort')
    and a = 'test'
    and (
        b like '123456%'
        --or 
        --c like '123456%'
    )
    order by id,d
    LIMIT 1000;

Limit  (cost=1328.48..329200.05 rows=1000 width=174) (actual time=6447.387..6449.560 rows=9 loops=1)
  ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=1328.48..6237117.82 rows=19019 width=174) (actual time=6447.386..6449.558 rows=9 loops=1)
        Sort Key: id, d
        Presorted Key: id
        Full-sort Groups: 1  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.63..6236261.96 rows=19019 width=174) (actual time=4260.425..6449.545 rows=9 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 4
              Workers Launched: 4
              ->  Parallel Index Scan foo_pkey on foo  (cost=0.57..6232996.56 rows=4755 width=174) (actual time=2074.052..5836.991 rows=2 loops=5)
                    Index Cond: (id >= 24481318)
                    Filter: ((a = 'test'::text) AND (ROW(id, d) > ROW(24481318, '0710123456'::text)) AND ((b ~~ '%123456%'::text) OR (c ~~ '%123456%'::text)))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 21535414
Planning Time: 0.186 ms
Execution Time: 6449.588 ms
```

I have already tried different combinations of indexes, but the current result is that with index the performance is worse.

Is there any suggestion how I can get a better result?

EDIT:
Tested the first suggestion with a combined GIN Index:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS foo_gin
   ON foo USING gin
   (a gin_trgm_ops,b gin_trgm_ops,c gin_trgm_ops,d gin_trgm_ops)
```

Query:

```
select *
    from foo
    where 
    (id) > (132111615)
    and a = 'test'
    and (
        b like '123456%'
        or 
        c like '123456%'
    )
    order by id
    LIMIT 1000
```

Query Plan

```
        Limit  (cost=1000.63..321778.82 rows=1000 width=174) (actual time=120909.920..120912.587 rows=9 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.63..6101881.20 rows=19019 width=174) (actual time=120909.918..120912.583 rows=9 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 4
        ->  Parallel Index Scan using foo_pkey on foo  (cost=0.57..6098615.79 rows=4755 width=174) (actual time=62580.499..120904.183 rows=2 loops=5)
              Index Cond: (id > 24481318)
              Filter: ((a = 'test'::text) AND ((b ~~ '%123456%'::text) OR (c ~~ '%123456%'::text)))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 21535414
Planning Time: 19.665 ms
Execution Time: 120912.642 ms
```

Unfortunately the index is not used.

Comment: Check the extension pgtrgm: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-INDEX

Comment: Please show DDL of any indexes you've defined

Comment: Why is `or c like '123456%'` commented out? Please either delete it entirely, or uncomment it if it's an essential part of your query.

Comment: Also, the `LIKE` pattern in your execution plan is different from the one in your query.

Comment: @Frank Heikens
I know the extension, but would you recommend to create a index over 5-7 columns with a GIN or GIST index?

@ Bohemian currently no indexes created. And the uncommented shows that there could be added one more column

@ Laurenz Albe Which one?

Comment: I think I would start with GIN, better precision but slower to update. It all depends on your data, your queries and usage pattern.

Comment: I'm currently testing the GIN index across all 4 columns.

Comment: @Frank Heikens I added the gin index in the post